# Create Ubuntu 14.04 system image and install on other machine

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, configuration, cd-image

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) installed in my laptop (core i5, 6GB RAM) and there are several software installed like R, Octave etc.
I want to create a system image and use that image to install Ubuntu in another laptop of same configuration. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program I suggest.

Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine backup and restore.

http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php